# Avoiding infinite re-rendering in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

I have a Supabase database called threads with 5 entries, I am trying to make a new React component for every column in the database but I am running into some issues.

The issue that it's giving me is that it's stopping the program to prevent an infinite loop, I'd assume this is because in my code I am updating my useState every time I render my Component which I am aware of, but I'm not sure how I would get around this problem.

Component.js:

```
import {useState} from "react";
import {supabase} from "../../utils/supabaseClient";

export default function Sidebar() {
    const [newThreads, setNewThreads] = useState([]);

    // this is where I am kinda stuck
    const threadList = [];
    (async () => {
        let {data: threads, error} = await supabase
            .from('threads')
            .select('thread_title');
        threadList.push(threads); // how do I get the current index of the loop (and limit it to only get 5 entries?)
        threadList.forEach(function (value) {
            console.log(value)
        })
    })();
    setNewThreads(threadList);

    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <div className="sidebar-widget">
                <span className="widget-title">New Threads</span>
            </div>
            <div className="sidebar-widget">
                <span className="widget-title">New Members</span>
                {(Object.entries(newThreads) || []).map(([key, value]) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="widget-cell">
                            <div className={"widget-cell-image"}/>
                            <div className="widget-cell-content">
                                <span className={"widget-cell-title"}>{value}</span>
                                <div className="widget-cell-values">
                                    <span className={"widget-cell-by-user"}>by harley_swift,</span>
                                    <span className={"widget-cell-time"}>22:02</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help with an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The way to get around the problem of infinite re-rendering is to use `useEffect` to fetch your data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this is where I am kinda stuck
    const threadList = [];
    (async () => {
        let {
            data: threads,
            error
        } = await supabase
            .from('threads')
            .select('thread_title');
        threadList.push(threads); // how do I get the current index of the loop (and limit it to only get 5 entries?)
        threadList.forEach(function(value) {
            console.log(value)
        })
    })();
    setNewThreads(threadList);
}, []); // note the empty dependency list
```

The empty dependency list is one of the ways you know the effect will only run once.

To only add 5 of the items to the list, you can slice the result (or check to see if `supabase` has a builtin way of doing this):

```
threadList.push(threads.slice(0, 5));
```

---

Finally, note that state changes are asynchronous and more so in your case because you are actually doing a fetch over the network.

If you wanted to get notified when `newThreads` has been updated, you can use another `useEffect` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (newThreads) {
    console.warn(newThreads.length);
  }
}, [newThreads]);
```

*The `if` statement is not really needed, but added for completeness*

This also applies for when you want to actually render the `newThreads`, you need to use conditional rendering to do that:

```
{
  (Object.entries(newThreads) || []).map(([key, value]) => {
    return (
      <div className="widget-cell">
        <div className={"widget-cell-image"} />
        <div className="widget-cell-content">
          <span className={"widget-cell-title"}>{value}</span>
          <div className="widget-cell-values">
            <span className={"widget-cell-by-user"}>by harley_swift,</span>
            <span className={"widget-cell-time"}>22:02</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }) || <div>Loading...</div>
}
```

Comment: I've tried actually implemented this code, and it looks like it all works, but one thing happens: When I print the length of newThreads, it returns sometimes 0 and sometimes 5, and sometimes the components don't render (in the Object.entries part). Do you know why? (it looks like it's not rendering on initial render)

Comment: @HarleySwift that depends on where you are printing the length. State changes are not synchronous. If you check the state at the wrong time, you may see something different than if you waited a bit longer. As for the components not rendering, that may also be related to the list not being populated on time. You can add a check to see if the list is ready before doing the rendering. I will update my answer

Comment: I just did some experimenting, I hardcoded the arraylist value in, and it worked perfectly. Do you think this has something to do with delayed/broken database retrieving? Is there a way I should be creating a new list that updates every 5 ish minutes that I can use instead of pulling it every time?

Comment: @HarleySwift Also yes, you can use `setTimeout` inside a `useEffect` to fetch however often you wish